# input element's onChange property using useState hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I'm having trouble with controlled react input element. In class components, we used to have a handler like this, on `onChange`:

```js
  handleChange(event) {
    const { name, value } = event.targeet
    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    });
  }
```

But in hooks, how do I achieve the same? There is no `name` property defined here.

```js
import React, { useState } from "react"

function App() {
  const [inputValue, setValue] = useState("reactjs")
  
  return (
    <div>
      <input
        value={inputValue}
        onChange= 
      />
    </div>
  )

  export default App
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need to store your state in an object, like so:

```
import React, { useState } from "react"

function App() {
    const [state, setState] = useState({})

    function handleChange(event) {
        const { name, value } = event.target
        setState({
            ...state,
            [name]: value
        })
    }
    
    return (
        <div>
            <input
                name="input1"
                value={state["input1"]}
                onChange={handleChange}
            />
            <input
                name="input2"
                value={state["input2"]}
                onChange={handleChange}
            />
        </div>
    )
}
```

Note, setState will set the entire state, not merging with the existing state, so you have to explicitly merge the new state with the old state (`{...state, [name]: value}`).

Answer (score 0):

One way of achieving this with hooks could be to put all of your inputs values in a single state, just like you used to do it.

```
function App() {
  const [inputsValue, setValues] = useState({})
  
  return (
    <div>
      <input
        value={inputsValue[name]}
        onChange={({ target: { name, value }}) => setValues(old => { ...old, [name]: value })}
      />
    </div>
  )

  export default App
}
```

You can then set a specific value by deconstructing the odl state value, and modiying the one you want with computed properties :

```
setValues(old => { ...old, [name]: value })
```